# Force GNU Sort Command to consider only the first N decimal points

Tags: linux, sort

Please consider a text file named `example` containing the following data:

```
0 0.2667328325084663 0.02243994752564071
0 1.86630577374265 0.02243994752564048
0 0.2401209140718633 0.02243994752564071
```

We sort `example`'s the 3rd column first and then the 2nd column by the following command:

```
sort -g -k 3,3 -k 2,2 <example > sortedExample
```

The new file `sortedExample` now contains the following:

```
0 1.86630577374265 0.02243994752564048
0 0.2401209140718633 0.02243994752564071
0 0.2667328325084663 0.02243994752564071
```

As can be seen from the 2nd column, its first row's data value is higher than that of the second row. This is expected as the 3rd column's first row `0.02243994752564048` is smaller than that of the second `0.02243994752564071`.

The problem is that `0.02243994752564048` and `0.02243994752564071` are the same up to the 15th decimal number, thus we can assume they have the same value in a wide range of applications.

Is there any way to tell `sort` to consider only the first `N` decimal points, e.g. 15 herein?

Comment: Based on the `-g` (general numeric sort) can we assume you are using the GNU version of `sort`? if so, it should accept an optional character position in the field specifier e.g. `-k 3.1,3.16`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@steeldriver gave the more eloquent answer (say we use `GNU version of sort` and would like to consider the first 6 decimal points):

```
sort -g -k 3.1,3.6 -k 2.1,2.6 <example > sortedExample
```

resulting in:

```
0 0.2401209140718633 0.02243994752564071
0 0.2667328325084663 0.02243994752564071
0 1.86630577374265 0.02243994752564048
```

---

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28849367/3393574):

First we truncate (say up to the 6th decimal points) the 2nd and 3rd columns with the following (For the moment this was applied it twice for each column, I will edit my answer in the course of time):

```
sed 's|\([0-9]\.[0-9]\{6\}\)[0-9]\{1,\}|\1|' example > interim
```

Then, the aforementioned command:

```
sort -g -k 3,3 -k 2,2 <interim2 > sortedExample
```

The desired outcome is obtained as:

```
0 0.240120 0.022439
0 0.266732 0.022439
0 1.866305 0.022439
```